# Deeplinking/Firebase dynamic link

Tags: android, ios, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm working with the firebase dynamic link, where a link is generated, and clicking on that link redirects the user to the appropriate page in the app or to appstore if the app is not available.
Just wondering if after installing, click on open button from the store is it possible to navigate the user to expected page from store itself?

Comment: You can open your app from there and one method will be called where you will receive the data that you passed and then you can redirect user to wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links. Dynamic links will direct a user to the page you linked them to in the app after installation.